# How to create date range as From date to To date from given dates excluding weekends

Tags: t-sql

I have a table `PTO`:

```
DECLARE @PTO TABLE 
             (
                 employee_id VARCHAR(50), 
                 pto_type VARCHAR(10), 
                 date VARCHAR(20)
             )

INSERT INTO @PTO 
VALUES ('12XY34', 'VACATION', '4/04/2019'),
       ('12XY34', 'VACATION', '4/05/2019'),
       ('12XY34', 'VACATION', '4/08/2019'),
       ('98XX99', 'SICK', '4/04/2019'),
       ('98XX99', 'SICK', '4/05/2019'),
       (‘12XY34’, ‘VACATION’, ‘4/10/2019’),
       (‘12XY34’, ‘VACATION’, ‘4/11/2019’)
```

I want result as below:

```
employee_id  pto_type  from_date  to_date
--------------------------------------------
  12XY34     VACATION  4/04/2019  4/08/2019
  98XX99     SICK      4/04/2019  4/05/2019
  12XY34    VACATION  4/10/2019  4/11/2019
```

Comment: 1. Please don't store dates as `varchar`. 2. I don't think it is possible to solve the problem using the given data. There is nothing there in the data that indicates why certain dates should be merged and which dates should be interpreted as new interval.

Comment: [What is a calendar table? How do I create one?](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

Comment: And also, [Gaps and islands](https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/sql-server-mvp-deep-dives/chapter-5)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select employee. Ptotype,  min(date) from, max(date) to
From PTO
Group by employee, ptotype
```

That is what you asked but what if person has multiple vacations?  Does data still look like this?

Comment: Thanks Saad for your answer. Yes there may be multiple vacations for employee. I have updated my question

Comment: The data seems inconsistent then.  Why is 12XY34 not from 4/4 to 4/5.  Why are there 3 rows in that set and 2 rows in next set, i.e. 4/10 to 4/11.  If answer is "because 98XX99 is in middle" then understand that a table is a "set", i.e. unordered collection - there is no implied ordereding of rows.  Either you will have to say that "take earliest date after start date as end date" or you will need some sort of "vactaion request id".

Comment: Thanks Saad, I understand the data is inconsistent. But this is how I am getting data and I have to insert into my table. For employee 12XY34 there ate two sets of records with different date range which means he has two PTOs with different date ranges. for first PTO which is from 4/04/2019 to 4/08/2019 there is weekend (6th and 7th Apr) in between hence I want From date  as 4/04/2019 and To date as 4/08/2019.

Comment: Well what is the 4/5 row doing there then?  Why is 4/5 not correct and 4/8 is correct.  Or why are 4/8 and 4/10 not incorrect?  I think you need to talk to the data owners about it.